# Definition of cumulant generating function

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions, cumulants

The following question comes from M. Kardar's "Statistical Physics of Particles". Let $x$ be a random variable with pdf $p(x)$. Kardar defines the "characteristic function" as the Fourier transform of $p(x)$; *i.e*.

$$
\tilde p(k)=\int dx\,p(x)\,e^{-ikx}
$$

I see why this is a useful definition: by differentiating both sides wrt $k$, we generate the moments of $p(x)$ (after setting $k=0$). Without further motivation, Kardar then introduces the "cumulant generating function"

$$
\ln\tilde p(k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-ik)^n}{n!}\langle x^n\rangle_c
$$

where $\langle\cdot\rangle_c$ denotes cumulant. Now, I understand we can exponentiate the above and equate the two expressions for $\tilde p(k)$, and thereby relate moments to cumulants. My question is: why is the cumulant generating function defined this way? Is it just because it yields such familiar results as

$$
\langle x^2\rangle_c
=\langle x^2\rangle - \langle x\rangle^2
$$

Is there any more intuition behind this defintion?

Comment: The characteristic function is multiplicative with respect to sums of independent random variables, which means its logarithm is additive. This tells you e.g. that variance is additive for sums of independent random variables but also that a similar result holds for all higher cumulants.